# Can I replace a shower door that has one edge joining with another glass pane?

Tags: doors, shower

I had a shower door that wouldn't close anymore and the hinges were generally rotting and it was falling apart. The original construction was shoddy.

The shower consists of a door with one edge of the frame against the tile/wall, and the other partially on a standalone wall piece, and the other half against a piece of glass that covers the rear of the shower. I apologize for describing this terribly but I don't know the correct terms for these types of showers (or anything home related). It is best seen in the pictures below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj3ni.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9Tjb.jpg]

My question is, is there any hope of just replacing the door part without also tearing out the other piece of glass? The frame at the top that looks seamless does break apart. If not, can you buy combination door/side glass piece sets at Home Depot or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen replacement doors at a place like Home Depot. Your situation looks like a custom made unit.  You probably will have to have it looked at by a local glass contractor/supplier to see if they can make a replacement door or hinge set up for ya. Unless you can actually find the make and model of what you have now, I doubt you will find a simple off the shelf replacement.